# Android Camera2 pictures appear rotated in gallery

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have made an app which takes pictures (portrait, landscape or selfie) using the [Google Camera2 sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic). Everything works, I can take the pictures, they are saved, etc.

But when I open my phone's (Samsung S7) gallery then all the selfies and portrait pictures are rotated 90 degrees. The landscape pictures are fine though. I have seen a lot of post about how to **read** images in the correct orientation, but what about saving them properly?

I have my own gallery in my app and there the pictures are loaded correctly (using Glide) without any special rotation fixing, so I am not sure what I did wrong and most importantly, how do I fix this?

Comment: Pull one of the images off of your device and examine it using `exiftool` or something. Or, toss together some code that uses the `com.android.support:exifinterface` edition of `ExifInterface`. In either case, you are looking to see if there is an orientation EXIF tag with the expected value. If there is, then the problem is not in saving the image, but a bug in the gallery app that you are using. You're welcome to try to manually rotate the image before saving (and remove the orientation tag), but you might not have enough heap space to do this.

Comment: If, OTOH, that tag is missing, then perhaps there is something wrong in how you are saving the image, and that would require a [mcve].

Comment: I ran exiftool on one of the selfies and I get an orientation Tag: `Rotate 270 CW`. So I guess it's something wrong with the gallery?

Comment: They also look fine when using a third party gallery app. So I guess it must be ok?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An image viewer is supposed to examine the EXIF tag and rotate the image in accordance with the orientation tag. This allows camera apps and similar software to save the images in whatever orientation they come in, without having to rotate the image before saving it.

Libraries like Glide and Picasso will do this for you, if you give them access to the full JPEG (e.g., `file` `Uri`, `content` `Uri`, `https` URL). That is because they have access to both the EXIF tags *and* the resulting `ImageView`, and so they can tell the `ImageView` to rotate the image.

However, not everybody uses such libraries. `ImageView` on its own deals with things like `Bitmap`, where those EXIF tags have been lost in the decoding process.

You, as the author of a camera app, have two main options here:

1. You could examine the EXIF tags, see that the image needs to be rotated, rotate it yourself, and save the rotated image (removing the orientation tag but arranging to retain the others). However, this may fail with an `OutOfMemoryError`, particular for camera images, as these images tend to be big.
2. You could shrug your shoulders and move on, as it's really not your problem. As you note, other gallery apps do not exhibit the issue, because they were tested adequately, and the original gallery app that you tried did not.

If you go with option #1, it turns into option #2 if you get the `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: I want to mention also that even going with option 1 it seems that this differs from phone to phone as the manufacturers seem to save images in different ways. I think I will just shrug it off then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @barouf: "it seems that this differs from phone to phone as the manufacturers seem to save images in different ways" -- oh, absolutely. From what I've seen, my guess is that it is tied to the camera chipset as much as anything else. Some will rotate the image for you. Others just set the EXIF tag. A few will be buggy and do neither, and you're stuck with trying to perhaps use sensors to determine how the device was held at the time.

Comment: Going with option 1, you don't necessarily need to examine EXIF. Your app controlling the capture, you have access to the orientation sensors, and sometimes this may help.

Comment: Another note, not only deficient gallery apps, also some external viewers don't display images with EXIF rotation tags correctly. It's their fault, but if you can afford true rotation, it's better. Unfortunately, rotation is a time-consuming and memory intensive task.

Comment: have you ever implemented camera2 api yet ?

Comment: your answer does not make sense dear..the question was asked related to custom camera using camera2 api and your answer is out of the frame

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [JPEG_ORIENTATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#JPEG_ORIENTATION) control in your still capture request?  If not, that may be the issue - that control tells the camera device how to rotate the final JPEG image to be right-side-up.

So you need to update the value in that control to describe how the image sensor currently lines up relative to the world.

To do that calculation, you'll need input from the accelerometer (which tells you which way is down), and then some basic math - reproducing this from the link above:

```
private int getJpegOrientation(CameraCharacteristics c, int deviceOrientation) {
  if (deviceOrientation == android.view.OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return 0;
  int sensorOrientation = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);

  // Round device orientation to a multiple of 90
  deviceOrientation = (deviceOrientation + 45) / 90 * 90;

  // Reverse device orientation for front-facing cameras
  boolean facingFront = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
  if (facingFront) deviceOrientation = -deviceOrientation;

  // Calculate desired JPEG orientation relative to camera orientation to make
  // the image upright relative to the device orientation
  int jpegOrientation = (sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;

  return jpegOrientation;
}
```

where the input deviceOrientation comes from the sensors API.